# double interpretation of Boolean algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

It bothers me that there seems to be only a flawed double interpretation of Boolean algebra in terms of classes and of propositions. One can say

A∪B indicates  union or inclusive disjunction

A∩B indicates   intersection or conjunction

A' indicates complement or negation

but when one comes to

A⊂B

one encounters a difficulty: if we say it indicates   subclass or implication we have a grammatical problem. In the other pairs above , the class interpretation yields another class ( e.g. A, B and A∪B are all classes) while the propositional interpretation makes them all propositions. However, in the case of A⊂B  , both interpretations are sentences. This creates a problem in that , e.g.,

A⊂(B ⊂C)

is grammatical interpreted propositionally but ungrammatical when interpreted in class theory.  I tried fixing it by using

A' ∪ B

for

A⊂B

but it doesn’t work (check it with a Venn diagram). Can we fix this?

Comment: Was $\subset$ really used as the symbol for implies in this context?  I would have figured it would have been $\implies$ or $\to$ or something else along those lines...  Using $\vee$ for or and using $\implies$ for implies, we would have in any case, $A\implies (B\implies C)$ is indeed equivalent to $A\implies (B' \vee C)$ which is equivalent to $A'\vee B'\vee C$.  I don't understand what you mean by "it doesn't work (check with a Venn diagram)."  Perhaps you confused $A\implies (B\implies C)$ with $(A\implies B)\wedge (B\implies C)$ or similar?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think he drew the Venn diagrams of $A\subset B$ and compared it with $A'\cup B$ and conclude they do not represent the same region, hence they have different meanings.

Comment: Because the corresponding ["set interpretation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Secondary_operations) of $p \to q$ is $\overline p \cup q$ (recall that $p \to q$ is $\lnot p \lor q$),

Comment: In which case, I do not understand how that could have happened... what does he think the venn diagram of $A\implies B$ look like?  What does he think the venn diagram of $A'\vee B$ looks like?  Perhaps it all comes down to a language issue and using weird symbols... trying to use set theory symbols instead.  Replacing $\vee$'s with $\cup$'s I can understand just fine.  Replacing $\implies$'s with $\subset$'s I cannot so easily understand... how would you go about drawing a venn diagram of "$A\subset B$" directly if not using a definition of it meaning $A'\cup B$ or similar?

Answer (score 3):

As "$A\subseteq B$" is a statement *about sets* and not a set in itself, I prefer to view its logical analogue as "$A\vdash B$", which is a statement *about formulas* and not a formula itself.

Therefore, in the context of Boolean algebra, "$A\subseteq B$" seem to be more properly translated as "entails" than as "implies".

---

The proper way to view $\to$, or logical implication, is then by $A\to B\equiv \lnot A\lor B$. Hence $\to$ is not a primitive notion in a Boolean algebra, but a defined one. This makes $A'\cup B$ the corresponding set theoretic analogue of $A\to B$.

Answer (score 2):

One immediate difference is that $\subset$ is used to make a claim about sets, while $\cap$ and $\cup$ are operators that work on sets. Indeed, where $A \cap B$ is another set (i.e. $\cap$ is function that takes in two sets and outputs a new set), $A \subset B$ is not a set ... but a claim.  So that's why $\subset$ does not have a logical operator counterpart.

Indeed, when you say:

> I tried fixing it by using
>
> A' ∪ B
>
> for
>
> A⊂B

that makes absolutely no sense: $A ' \cup B$ is a set, but $A \subset B$ is not a set in the first place.